# Oracle PL/SQL Return recordset and specific column(from recordset) in seperate variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I need to return value from procedure, recordset and single value(extract from recordset)

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
    EMP_ID number;
    EMP_NAME varchar2(20);
    EMP_FLAG char(1);
);

CREATE TABLE SALARY
(
    EMP_ID number;
    EMP_SAL number;
);

BEGIN
  insert into EMP values(10,'John','N');
  insert into EMP values(20,'May','Y');

  insert into SALARY values(10,10000);
  insert into SALARY values(10,25000);
END;
/
```

Here is my Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(Flag in char(1),curEMP out SYS_REFCURSOR,Sal out number)
  v_sal    number;   
  v_emp_id number;
  v_name   varchar2(20);                               
AS
    open curEMP for
    select e.emp_id
            ,e.emp_name
            ,s.sal
    from emp e
    left join sal s on e.emp_id  = s.emp_id
    where e.emp_flag = Flag;

    loop
        fetch curEMP into v_emp_id,v_name,v_Sal; --in real life there are more than 20+ fields
      exit when curEMP%notfound;
    end loop;
    Sal := v_sal;
END TEST;
/
```

Script to call Procedure

```
set serveroutput on;
variable cr refcursor;
variable sal number;

exec TEST('Y',:cr,:sal);
print cr;
print sal;
```

Here is the output

Output

```
sal
25000
```

However, I need output like this

--Output from cursor list

```
emp_id emp_name sal     
20     May   25000
```

--from sal variable

```
sal     
25000
```

Comment: Two problems here: first, when you return a REF CURSOR you are supposed to open it but not fetch from it. The program that calls you is supposed to do the fetching, then close the cursor. Second, if your query returns more than one row then the rows may be returned in any order, so the content of SAL might change. You need to do a separate query to get the precise SAL value your caller wants.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I am now try to follow your instruction.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your table DDL and procedure, but I guess you have executed the procedure anyway.

To fetch all the records, You can use the only `cursor` and open it in the `procedure`, there is no need for `looping` through a `cursor` in your `procedure`.

see the `procedure` and its call in the following example:

> ```
> SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST (
>   2      FLAG     IN       CHAR, -- size can not be given in the input parameter
>   3      CUREMP   OUT      SYS_REFCURSOR
>   4      --SAL      OUT      NUMBER -- no need of this parameter
>   5  ) AS
>   6      --V_SAL      NUMBER; -- all variables are not needed
>   7      --V_EMP_ID   NUMBER;
>   8      --V_NAME     VARCHAR2(20);
>   9  BEGIN
>  10      OPEN CUREMP FOR SELECT
>  11                          E.EMP_ID,
>  12                          E.EMP_NAME,
>  13                          S.EMP_SAL
>  14                      FROM
>  15                          EMP E
>  16                          LEFT JOIN SALARY S ON E.EMP_ID = S.EMP_ID
>  17                      WHERE E.EMP_FLAG = FLAG;
>  18  --    LOOP -- looping is not needed
>  19  --        FETCH CUREMP INTO
>  20  --            V_EMP_ID,
>  21  --            V_NAME,
>  22  --            V_SAL; --in real life there are more than 20+ fields
>  23  --        EXIT WHEN CUREMP%NOTFOUND;
>  24  --    END LOOP;
>  25
>  26  --    SAL := V_SAL;
>  27  END TEST;
>  28  /
>
> Procedure created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Testing the procedure now.

> ```
> SQL> VAR x REFCURSOR;
> SQL> exec test('Y',:x);
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> SQL> print :x
>
>     EMP_ID EMP_NAME                EMP_SAL
> ---------- -------------------- ----------
>         20 May                       25000
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank for help. However, I need 2 variables to show.
First, VAR x REFCURSOR; same as your output (Recordset emp_id,emp_name,emp_sal).
Second variable ,only 1 column, sal which store 25000

Comment: But you are getting it in the cursor then why you want it in different variable again?

Comment: Im sorry, I dont know the reason.However, this is the requirement from another team.

Comment: @SNPalita You need to explicitly declare the variable  if you want all the variables as separate.